# Creating a virtual environment is not working with Python 3.8 on Windows using built-in venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I have tried creating a 'venv' in both Python 3.7 and 3.8 with the same result. The command I am using is

`python3.8 -m venv C:\Users\xxxxxx\PycharmProjects\TestVenv\venv`

I get an error in the output
`Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

The directories you would expect to see are created, however, that 'activate.bat' script and many of the usual scripts seen in the Scripts directory are not created.

```
    Directory: C:\Users\xxxxxx\PycharmProjects\TestVenv\venv


    Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
    ----                -------------         ------ ----
    d-----       28/11/2019     04:46                Include
    d-----       28/11/2019     04:46                Lib
    d-----       28/11/2019     04:46                Scripts
    -a----       28/11/2019     04:46            122 pyvenv.cfg
```

The contents of the Scripts directory are:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\xxxxxx\PycharmProjects\TestVenv\venv\Scripts


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       28/11/2019     04:46         416840 python.exe
-a----       28/11/2019     04:46         415816 pythonw.exe
```

Of course, this means I cannot activate my virtual environment. I am not sure if it is relevant, but I am running this in a VDI. I have local admin privileges and my colleagues, with the same privilges and set-ups, are able to get their virtual environments working.

EDIT:

FIXED

Fixed by uninstalling an Anaconda installation I had. Not sure why this was clashing with my standard Python installation.

Comment: can you share full error msg (the system cannot find path one)

Comment: I also had problems on Linux. Have you tried using virtualenv?

Comment: That was the full error message. Yes, I tried virtualenv too with no luck. So, I fixed the issue but caused myself a different one. I had an parallel installation of Anaconda which, when I deleted it, allowed my to create virtual environments with venv as expected. Not sure why Anaconda was getting in the way...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by uninstalling an Anaconda installation I had. Not sure why this was clashing with my standard Python installation.